# What are the differences between Gopi Chandan and normal chandan (sandalwood)?

Tags: vishnu, belief, vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism, japa

I have generally known the Gaudiya Vaishnavism (Krishna rooted) based sects specifically applying the Gopi Chandan based *tilaks* on their body.

The other Vaishnavism sects might or might not limit with Gopi Chandan only, but as far as I have known, they'll apply the normal chandan (sandalwood) based *tilaks* too, besides the *gopi-chandan* variety too.

So, what's the difference between both kinds of *chandans* in terms of origin, significance and uses, as per the relevant religio-theological beliefs, and the stories found in the scriptures?

Moreover, why is *Chandan* (sandalwood) itself considered divine or sacred and mostly intrinsically related with Lord Vishnu or his manifestations, especially the White *Chandan* variety ? Example : Astrologers recommend using either the Tulasi beads rosary or the  White  Chandan rosary, to do *japam-dhyanam* for Lord Vishnu (or his avataras).